# knockout.js and multiple bindings performance and maintenance

Tags: knockout.js

Should I combine these bindings into one binding?  Will that boost performance?  Also can I call bindings explicitly inside a parent binding so I can still have some encapsulation of logic.

```
<div class="game clearfix draggable-active draggable-item" data-bind="
draggableCss: { game: $data }, 
draggableGameHandler : { disabled: (!$data.Matchup || $data.Occupied), disabledDrop: ($data.Disabled() || $data.Occupied) }, 
click: function() { alert('test') }">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use the third argument of the binding handler to access the other bindings on an element.  This is what is used for things like `optionsText`, `optionsValue`, `valueUpdate`, etc., as they are not real bindings.

So, if you have a binding like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.draggableGameHandler = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
         var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

         //can access allBindings.draggableCss and allBindings.draggableDrop
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {

    }
};
```

As far as a performance boost, it kind of depends on what you are doing. If you are repeating logic/work in multiple bindings that you could share in one, then you may see a boost.

Comment: I am repeating this binding on a grid like UI with alot of elements.

Comment: I think that it depends what you are doing.  If you are attaching lots of event handlers to each cell, then you might get a performance boost by using event delegation either like: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html or in the plugin that I created: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-delegatedEvents

Comment: Interesting Ill look into that since it looks like an option for my performance issue.

Comment: let me know if you need any help. definitely if you are using lots of events in grid cells, it can help